# Com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

Activator is running in local, but not on server:

Here are the logs:

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
  at controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:24)
  while locating controllers.Application
    for parameter 1 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:67)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:220)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:220)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:31)
    at controllers.Application$$FastClassByGuice$$b5b6aa19.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get$lzycompute(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:78)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:47)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:22)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)

2) Error injecting constructor, java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
  at controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:24)
  while locating controllers.Application
    for parameter 1 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:67)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:220)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:220)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
    for parameter 0 at play.DefaultApplication.<init>(DefaultApplication.java:30)
  at play.DefaultApplication.class(DefaultApplication.java:30)
  while locating play.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.Application
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:31)
    at controllers.Application$$FastClassByGuice$$b5b6aa19.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get$lzycompute(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:78)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:47)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:22)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)

3) Error injecting constructor, java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
  at controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:24)
  while locating controllers.Application
    for parameter 1 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:67)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:220)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:220)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:31)
    at controllers.Application$$FastClassByGuice$$b5b6aa19.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get$lzycompute(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:78)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:47)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:22)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
```

Comment: You are trying to get something that not exists from the `Option`. Could you add some code to the question? What are you trying to do here: `at controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:31)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the inner exception, go through the stack trace from top to bottom:

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:31)
    at controllers.Application$$FastClassByGuice$$b5b6aa19.newInstance(<generated>)
...
```

The first two lines are not from your own code, but they obviously must have been called by your code somewhere. The next line in the stacktrace looks much more promising:

```
at controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:31)
```

This is likely where your error is. Check line 31 of your `Application.scala` file.